# Average values from different table on join

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `reviews` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `average` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `house_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `reviews` (`id`, `average`, `house_id`) VALUES
(1, '10.00', 1),
(2, '10.00', 1);
ALTER TABLE `reviews`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `reviews`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

CREATE TABLE `dummy_reviews` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `average` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `house_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `dummy_reviews` (`id`, `average`, `house_id`) VALUES
(0, '2.00', 1);
ALTER TABLE `dummy_reviews`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

AND the query

```
SELECT
  AVG(r.average) AS avg1,
  AVG(dr.average) AS avg2
FROM
  reviews r
LEFT JOIN
  dummy_reviews dr ON r.house_id = dr.house_id
```

the result is

```
avg1        avg2    
10.000000   2.000000
```

All good by now but (10 + 2) / 2 = 6 ... wrong result

I need (10+10+2) / 3 = 7,33 ... How can I get this result?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0b75f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have values joined and as such you wont have 3 rows, you will have 2. What you need is a union so you can have all rows from your average tables and do the calculation from it. Like this:

```
select avg(average) from
  (select average from reviews
   union all
   select average from dummy_reviews
  ) queries
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0b75f/3

Comment: Your solution is right. Is there any other solution ... not using union ?

Comment: With your current design and desired result I'm afraid not. Why you need it in other way? Maybe if you explain it I can think in a way of doing so.

Comment: desire result is a part of a big join ( 8 tables ) with different parameters ... I am thinking to integrate somehow your solution ... else I will need to use your solution ... and pass the same parameters

Comment: Take a look at Gordon's answer. It may fit your requirement better. I've just learned that it could be done in another way :)

Answer (score 3):

Jorge's answer is the simplest approach (and I duly upvoted it).  In response to your comment, you can do the following:

```
select ( (coalesce(r.suma, 0) + coalesce(d.suma, 0)) /
         (coalesce(r.cnt, 0) + coalesce(d.cnt, 0))
       ) as overall_average
from (select sum(average) as suma, count(*) as cnt
      from reviews
     ) r cross join
     (select sum(average) as suma, count(*) as cnt
      from dummy_reviews
     ) d;
```

Actually, I suggest this not only because of your comment.  Under some circumstances, this could be the better performing code.

Comment: Awesome answer :) ... thanks. Thank @JorgeCampos his answer is right also

Comment: @Florin . . . I appreciate your accepting this answer (I really do), but I think you should accept Jorge's.  It is simpler, correct, and was first.